# How do I resolve morale issues?

Tags: state-of-decay

Throughout the game members of your party will frequently experience issues which effect the group's morale. For example; fear, sadness, loneliness, etc.

[image]

How can I combat these issues and resolve the problems resulting in a reduction of the group's morale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing Morale missions is only the "Emergency" solution. When you have a lot of survivors with low morale, you will be overwhelmed with these types of mission as well as "Missing Survivor" if someone panic and run away.

The only way you can prevent this type of mission from showing up (at least for a short while) is improving the survivors' Attitudes. For example, the angry ones require "Anger Management", the sad ones require "Melancholy" mission, etc, so you need to improve their attitude to something neutral (like Concerned) or positive (like Charitable).

Switch to the characters with negative attitudes and complete missions with them to improve their attitude.

- Killing Hordes (only when the note "Too many Hordes" appears) is the
  most efficient, but rarely available method.
- Bringing resources home.
- Aiding another survivor in a Supply Run mission (note: completing this mission improve both survivors' attitude)
- Clearing Infestations.
- Bringing needed components home (for example, when building/upgrading facilities).
- Finishing a task with facility (for example, the Healer character receives an attitude boost after creating painkiller/stims, the Chef character after completing a Feast)
- Bringing home belongings of a fallen ally.

Check out the SoD wiki [Attitudes](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Attitudes) article for more info.

Comment: At the point there's a 'morale issue' the upset character is 'on a mission' and can't be selected.

Comment: Killing hordes is not 'rarely' available, it's the #1 super easy way to keep everybody's morale high all the time. Just set up your outposts and they'll do the work for you.

Comment: @DCShannon: Killing Hordes only improves Attitudes when the note "Too many Hordes" appears. And you actually have to kill the Horde BEFORE the outposts kill them to improve the character's attitude.

Comment: You say "When you have a lot of survivors with low morale, you will be overwhelmed with these types of mission as well as "Missing Survivor" if someone panic and run away". I'm referring to increasing morale, not attitude. Destroying hordes with outposts increases morale. I realize now that you're referring to the attitude mission called "Killing Hordes", not the simple act of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

When you're not in a mission (whether a 'green' mission where you're actively on your way to complete an objective, or a 'blue' mission where you're returning from a completed objective or being forced to survey the area) the missions to resolve morale related issues should appear on the map;

[image]

Sometimes it is not always obvious that you're in a mission, so if in doubt, exit the map and check the minimap to see if you've got any arrows pointing off to a specific location.

Simply go talk to the person in question and accept the mission, in all instances this seems to be heading off to a random location to kill all of the zombies while having a minimal conversation about the state of things.

The mission (and morale issue) will be resolved once you've returned back to base with the person who had the issue.

Comment: Destroying human-shaped things is apparently therapeutic. Who knew!

Answer (score 0):

Having someone with Counseling may prevent it from getting to this point.

Comment: That's incorrect. Counseling may reduce chances that a fight would break out at home, or a depressed character would commit suicide, but it does not improve morale/attitude. It only buys you a little more time to solve things before it's too late.